# Keep sending malformed TCP header using bsd/socket api in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, raw-sockets

long story short I'm currently experimenting with **BSD/Socket C API**.

I want to try to emulate a full **TCP Handshake.**
The first thing that I have to do is send the first **SYN packet** to the host, in my case **the router (192.168.1.1)**.

Here is the **snippet** of the code that generates the **SYN packet**.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/23758682/

Here is what I'm getting from **wireshark** when I'm running this program as

```
sudo ./sendsyn -h 192.168.1.1 -p 80 -i enp5s0
```

http://prnt.sc/dsnmgq

The code is compiled on linux x86, 64 bit with GCC

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 6.2.1 20160830
```

I want the code to be compliant just for the x86 platform and run only on Linux. I don't care about portability that much.

Also, I'm using in gcc this flags.

```
gcc  -DDEBUG_MODE  -std=gnu11 -fno-strict-aliasing 
-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith 
-Wcast-align -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations 
-Winline -Wuninitialized -Wstrict-prototypes 
-Werror -Wno-variadic-macros
```

So be aware that when compiling I'm turning off the **-fno-strict-aliasing** rules.

### The problems

**Why the tcp header dosen't show as tcp header in wireshark?**

Previously I tried sending the packet as a struct like

```
typedef struct packet_t {
  struct iphdr iph;
  struct tcphdr tcph;
}__attribute__((packed)) packet_t;
```

And now in the code I first create a **uint8_t datagram** and after I've filled all the information in my **IP Header** and **TCP Header** I **memcpy** into the datagram and then after send them over the wire.

**Why the ip header flags are not set to 0x4000(don't fragment) ?**

Can anyone provide a solution to my problem in a snippet along with some good explanations?

Comment: There are three possible causes: 1) padding 2) network byte order 3) an error in your checksum. Best way would be to hexdump your struct (as individual `uint8_t`) after you created it. Then, manually compute the checksum. The fragment_offset in your wireshark dump looks suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

```
iph.frag_off = 0x4000;
```

this line should be

```
iph.frag_off = htons(0x4000);
```

Because 0x4000 is 16 bit wide and all values that needs more than 8 bits to be stoder should always be transformed into network byte order(big endian).

Now this is working, see wireshark
[tcp syn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hovE.png)